# WooCommerce & Caching

Tags: plugins, cache

I have a div that displays the total amount of products the customer has in their cart, however this isn't updating as I have caching on (W3 Total Cache).

Is there a workaround for this?

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

Read the [WooCommerce docs](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/integration/configuring-caching-plugins/).  I've run in to this before, and the following pages cannot be cached:

- Cart
- My Account
- Change Password
- Edit Address
- View Order
- Checkout
- Pay
- Order Received

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use what's called "fragment caching" to regenerate only part of the page each time. http://css-tricks.com/wordpress-fragment-caching-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

First, try these common Solutions that have worked for others:

Disable your caching plugin (which can cause the JS to stop working) and see if that fixes it

Try using a different browser but as a user, not ADMIN

Go to your WooCommerce settings page and Untick "Prepend product permalinks with shop base page (shop)"

Allow your browser to accept cookies and make sure javascript is enabled

Comment: Don't use bold letters in the manner you did. This is the same as shouting, which is not allowed and bad manners

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not need to exclude your cart and other pages listed. There is a note at the bottom of the doc you linked to that states:

> Note, WC 1.4.2+ sets the DONOTCACHEPAGE constant which should mean you
>   can skip this step